# How to compare the NSTimeInterval(NSNumber Objects) inside a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsmutablearray, nstimeinterval

I have two NSMutableArrays(arrayContainsGoodClicks and arrayContainsBadClicks). I am initializing these Arrays with some NSTimeInterval values when the relevant Good and Bad buttons are clciked. Now my requirement is, i am getting responses from a webservice call with some TimeIntervals. Now, i want compare the NSTimeInterval values that i am getting from the Webservice responses with the values that i have stored in the two arrays. Please find below the code.

```
question answer="t" qno="1" tin="71" title="Greet" tout="73"
question answer="t" qno="2" tin="74" title="Have Name Tag" tout="77
question answer="t" qno="3" tin="78" title="Greet" tout="83"
```

I am getting the response in the above mentioned format. I am parsing my file and storing the relevant details of NSTimeInterval Values. Now i want to compare the timeIntervals between 71 and 73 seconds(74 and 77,78 and 83 respectively). I have my arrays which contains all the timeInterval values at which the user has clicked the Good and Bad buttons.

```
    -(void)onClickOfGood{
//NSLog(@"The current playback time in good:%g",moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime);
currentPlaybackTime = moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime;
NSNumber *goodTimeIntervals = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:currentPlaybackTime];
[arrayContainsGoodClicks addObject:goodTimeIntervals];
NSLog(@"The total count of Array is: %i",[arrayContainsGoodClicks count]);
NSLog(@"The Array contains : %@",arrayContainsGoodClicks);}

-(void)onClickOfBad{
NSLog(@"The current playback time in bad: %g",moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime);
currentPlaybackTime = moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime;
NSNumber *goodTimeIntervals = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:currentPlaybackTime];
[arrayContainsBadClicks addObject:goodTimeIntervals];
NSLog(@"The total count of Array is: %i",[arrayContainsBadClicks count]);
NSLog(@"The Array contains Bad Clicks are: %@",arrayContainsBadClicks);}
```

My arrays contains the following sample details...

```
The Array containing Good Clicks are : (
"2.065027933",
"3.153256308",
"4.216946226",
"4.94465584",
"5.688772132",
"6.48904879",
"7.256447126",
"8.000711516000001",
"8.760312588",
"9.537493762",
"10.45637486",
"11.153212146",
"11.880587144",
"12.672884372",
"13.52852395"
```

)

```
The Array containing Bad Clicks are: (
"2.70485684",
"3.713548251",
"4.593316639",
"5.353822771",
"6.049754725",
"6.930190204",
"7.592959653",
"8.353438538000001",
"9.074305708000001",
"9.905327347",
"10.809726701",
"11.448938757",
"12.321753456",
"14.106061449"
```

)

Can someone please help me on how to compare the NSTimeIntervals in my arrays and the received responses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems quite trivial if you have the data in the correct format. NSTimeInterval is a `typedef double` so you can do comparisons using basic operators

```
for(NSNumber* click in arrayContainsGoodClicks) {
    NSTimeInterval clickTimeInterval = [click doubleValue];     
    if(clickTimeInterval > 71.0 && clickTimeInterval < 73.0 ) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But the problem here is...everytime the button is clicked at the right time interval, the array is getting added with the same object. I am adding the object after the if condition check this way.. if(clickTimeInterval > 71.0 && clickTimeInterval < 73.0 ) {            
            NSNumber *filteredGoodTimeIntervals = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:clickTimeInterval];
            [filteredArrayContainsGoodClicks addObject:filteredGoodTimeIntervals];
            NSLog(@"The Filtered Array containing Good Clicks are : %@",filteredArrayContainsGoodClicks);
        }  Can u please check if i am wrong?

Comment: Hi @amleszk . Can u please explain me what for(NSNumber* click in arrayContainsGoodClicks)  means? What will it check for?